# my nodejs code does not recognize css file

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, root

code in app.js:

```
app.listen(PORT_)

 app.use('/',route);
```

i enter following code in route.js

```
 app.use(express.static('routing'));
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./MainPage.html'));

});
```

html file is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Style.css">

    <title></title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="header">Please select following items:</h1>
    <ol class="ol">
        <li>Get all product</li>
        <li>Get by ID</li>
        <li>Post product</li>
    </ol>
    <input class="inp" type="text" placeholder="1,2,3">
    <button class="btn"type="submit">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

location of html and css file is as fllow:

```
app.js ---> root
route.js ---> root/routing/route.js
MainPage.html ---> root/routing/MainPage.html
Style.css ---> root/routing/Style.css
```

following code does not recognize css file only recognize html file.

Comment: If you use `static` you don't need `sendFile`, since the HTML page is already served since it is in the `routing` folder

Comment: Works OK for me. Are you sure this is your exact code and folder structure?